# How to open a file in Eclipse in an embedded fashion?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, doxygen, chm

I would like to open a .chm file in Eclipse. But it does not support these files. If I wanted a workaround, how should I go about it?

I have looked into writing plug-ins to do so. The only way I would be able to view .chm as an Eclipse Help Plug-in would be to convert .chm to DITA and then DITA to Eclipse help files. But there's no clear cut way to do this. There isn't much help online either. Any suggestions?

I need an automate-able way to do this. I will have a .chm file (for documentation of the source code generated by Doxygen) pushed to a repo that someone will pull and open up in Eclipse along with the code. They should be able to use the search functionalities provided in a chm file. A normal HTML page does not provide these.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to accomplish but it looks like you want first convert the documentation from the source files to `.chm` and show these results in Eclipse? There is a plugin / extension available `eclox` for eclipse (I have no experience with it and it is not maintained by doxygen), maybe you should have a look at this.

Comment: Is Eclipse installed under Windows? Which version?

Comment: The version is 4.6.3. It is the Eclipse Neon for C++ IDE.