# How to install Eclipse Help Plug-in generated by Doxygen?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, doxygen

I used Doxygen to generate index files in addition to HTML files to produce a Eclipse Help Plug-in(plugin.xml and toc.xml). I zipped up all the HTML files into a doc.zip. I placed doc.zip, plugin.xml and toc.xml into a folder with the same name as ECLIPSE_DOC_ID in the Doxy config file. I placed this folder into the plugins directory under eclipse. I restarted eclipse but my documentation does not show up under Help -> Help Contents. What am I missing?

Comment: See your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051752/how-to-open-a-file-in-eclipse-in-an-embedded-fashion. You should probably have a look at the eclox plugin / extension for eclipse (I have no experience with it and it is not maintained by doxygen), maybe you should have a look at this.

Comment: You have to place the folder in `dropins`, not in `plugins`. And the folder must also contain a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: Crosslinking a doxygen-github-issue: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6434